# How to Handle Ex43C0AC|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception, exchange-online

I am running below ExchangeOnline command for thousands of user, and for few of them I am getting bello exception. I am using try-catch, even though this exception is not handled  and it is thrown on console. Could you please help me catch this exception?

```
try{
    Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -mailbox <mailbox UPN>
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception
}
```

Eception thrown on console:
`Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics: Ex43C0AC|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException|The operation couldn't be performed because 'abc@domain.com' couldn't be found.`

I have tried normal try-catch block.

Comment: I think the exception is working you are just displaying the message on the screen because you have $_.Exception.  Just remove the catch and nothing will be display when you get the exception.